# How to import a custom widget (PyQT) into Python Code

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I created a custom widget with Qt Designer (then created the py file with pyuic5)  but I'm unable to use it in my code. I searched a lot about this and I found that I'm supposed to use something like this:

```
import MyWidget
self.MyWidget = MyWidget.Ui_Form()
self.MyWidget.setupUi(self)
```

When I try to add it to my grid using:

```
grid.addWidget(self.MyWidget, 4 ,2)
```

I get the following error code:

> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>   addWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_Form'
>   addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment,
>   Qt.AlignmentFlag] = 0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_Form'
>   addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, int, int, alignment:
>   Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = 0): argument 1 has unexpected
>   type 'Ui_Form'

The error makes sense and I kind of understand where it comes from but I don't know how to fix it and how to use my widget.

```
Code of my widget generated with pyuic5:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(Form)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 70, 64, 23))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 40, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(Form)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 90, 160, 29))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Frecuencia"))
```

Btw, the class for window and all the other stuff works correctly. I just posted the piece of code I need help with. I used the MyWidget.Ui_Form() in the **init** method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ui_Form` is not a widget, it is a class that serves to fill a widget, so the simple solution would be the following:

```
import MyWidget

...
form = MyWidget.Ui_Form()
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
form.setupUi(w)
grid.addWidget(w, 4 ,2)
...
```

But the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) recommends creating a class that inherits from the appropriate widget and fills in it:

```
import MyWidget

class SomeWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, MyWidget.Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SomeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    ...
    w = SomeWidget()
    grid.addWidget(w, 4 ,2)
```